# Why does Sitecore 8.2 not support Windows 7 OS?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.2

Windows 7 was removed from the operating system requirements list when 8.2 came out. Is there a technical reason for that, or is it just falling off the support list because of it's age?

I'm seeing nothing in the changelog for 8.2 that lends to it not running on Windows 7.

Keep in mind this is for development purposes only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official Microsoft Support for Windows 7 has ended or is ending. If Microsoft won't support the OS, it stands to reason Sitecore will not.

[Windows lifecycle fact sheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet)

Comment: Certainly it makes sense when considering the lifecycle, but working in an enterprise that's not ready to convert I am looking for information on if it's a technical reason it's not supported or a simple end-of-life reason.

Comment: A technical reason would mean inability to run/execute. There is none that I am aware of.